# Performing table join in pgadmin

Tags: pgadmin

I am trying to join the task table to wr2_descending but getting confused. The id column seems to be used for joining them. However, there is quad_id in task table, and 2 different id's gid and pr_id  in wr2_descending and am wondering which id to equate the quad_id from the task table to the id in wr2_descending. The wrspr and pr columns from the wr2_descending also looks so similar to me and includes the same values.

[image]

Code:

```
SELECT
  task_table.quad_id 
  wrs2_descending.gid
FROM task_table
JOIN wrs2_descending ON task_table.quad_id=wrs2_descending.gid
```

Comment: For each row in the data output, quad id from task_table has value 129050, 127055, 129051, 010062, 011062,........ gid from wrs2_descending has values as 1,2,3,....     pr_id from wrs2_descending as 1.0000000,2.0000000,3.0000000,...... I am wondering how to perform join if we consider id as a common field.

Comment: If you have further detail to add to your question, please add it to the question itself by editing the question - that is preferred to having additions in the comments.

Comment: I think you are asking which columns form the primary-key and foreign-key relationship for a one:many relation. Are there table constraints added to this database that would show you how the tables are related?